# Linear Systems and Kernels

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So My A is built upon the equations below:

```
    eq1 := x+3*y+10*z+2 = -w; 
    eq2 := 2*y+5*z+2*w+x = -3;
    eq3 := -x+5*z-2-3*w = 0
```

The question states the following

we know that the vector  x0 = (1, 2, -1, 3) satisfies a system of linear equations 
Ax=b with some non-zero vector b element in R3 and matrix A, and that the vector
u = (3, 1, 0, -2) is in the kernel of A.

(a) Find another solution of Ax = b different from x0, Explain.

```
My Answer: If u is a vector Au=b the every solution of the equation Ax =b is one of the form x=u+z for some vector z in the kernal, so we solve for z= x-u thus Az=b.
```

(b) Is the given information sufficient to find all solutions of the system if we also know that the nullity of A is equal to 2?  Find all solutions, or explain why this information is insufficient.

```
(Not Sure)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution space of a linear equation system $AX=b$ is a coset of the $ker(A)$, whose representative is any solution of the system. For the case in the question the solution space is then $x_0+ ker(A)$. So, to determine all solutions we need to know exactly $ker(A)$.

If the nullity of $A$ is $1$, then $ker(A)= \langle u \rangle$ and the solution space is $x_0 + \langle u \rangle$, but if the nullity is $2$, then $ker(A)$ can't be determined. Hence we can't find the whole solution space.

Comment: what do you mean exactly ker(A) is that A with GJE applied ?

Comment: It is kernel of $A$.

Comment: im kind of confused for the first part with the Kernal, isnt kernel solving the system of equation Ax=0

Comment: yes, it is. If you have a linear map $f: V \rightarrow W$ represented by the matrix $A$, then you have $V/ker(A)\cong Im(f)$; and an element $b \in Im(f)$ corresponds to the solution space of the system $AX=b$, i.e. the solution space is just an element in $V/ker(A)$ and it is equal to $x_0 +ker(A)$ where $x_0$ is any vector in the solution space. This is called isomorphism theorem or fundamental theorem in groups, rings and modules( vector spaces are modules).